# Hitting future call limit with Geocoding trigger

Tags: trigger, governorlimits, callout, future, geolocation

This trigger seems to work pretty well for Geocoding accounts...

```
 trigger AccountGeocode on Account (after insert, after update)
    {
    system.debug('AccountGeocode trigger fired');

    if(System.isBatch() || System.isFuture()) {
        system.debug('Cannot call future methods when this trigger is executed by a future or batch method');
    }
    else {
        for(Account a : Trigger.new) {
            //Will only geocode records while we still have available future calls, so some records may not be geocoded
            if(Limits.getFutureCalls() >= Limits.getLimitFutureCalls()) {
                break;
            }

            if(Trigger.isInsert) {
                    //Call a future method that tries to populate the Geolocation field
                    AccountGeocodeCallout.getLocation(a.id);
              }
              else if(Trigger.isUpdate) {
                    //Call a future method that tries to populate the Geolocation field (if and only if an address field has been changed)
                    Account oldAccount = Trigger.oldMap.get(a.Id);

                    if(oldAccount.ShippingStreet != a.ShippingStreet || 
                        oldAccount.ShippingCity != a.ShippingCity ||
                        oldAccount.ShippingState != a.ShippingState ||
                        oldAccount.ShippingPostalCode != a.ShippingPostalCode ||
                        oldAccount.ShippingCountry != a.ShippingCountry)
                        {
                            AccountGeocodeCallout.getLocation(a.id);
                        }
             }
        }
    } 
}
```

however I'm still getting emails like the following on bulk updates and confused by how this is happening considering that I'm checking the limits in the trigger.

```
Apex script unhandled trigger exception by user/organization:

AccountTrigger: System.LimitException: Too many future calls: 11
```

Comment: Brad -- you might want to check out Dan Appleman's brilliant async pattern at Dreamforce 13 -- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZqqiIg_mynY it allows for unlimited async events (e.g. 'future') through a clever use of scheduled apex-batch apex-customobj.

Answer (score 1):

I just noticed that the trigger that is throwing the exception is not the same trigger that is checking the limits. *facepalm*